# Regex pattern to limit character numbers

Tags: regex, perl

The regex expression is Perl-style.

I need to find these patterns: **<@U03AEKYL4>**

They all start same way : **<@**; they all have 9 characters after the @ (it these characters I want to catch); they all end with **>**.

> This regex expression do the job: `/\<@(.*?)\>/`.
>
> But I am in trouble when it comes to this : `<@U03AEKWTL|agreen>.`
>   This expression match but I don't want it.

I can't find a way to either limit to 9 characters or stop when I meet **|**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=<\@)[^|>]{9}(?=>|\|)
```

Try this.Use lookarounds to do the job for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/12

---

@ikegami points out it's much faster to not use lookarounds.

```
             Rate lookaround      basic
lookaround 69.9/s         --       -89%
basic       644/s       821%         --
```

Still, the difference is small (14 µs vs 1.6 µs), but the faster one is also the simpler one, so it's best all around.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

my %tests = (
   lookaround => 'my ($match) = $str =~ /(?<=<\@)([^|>]{9})(?=[|>])/',
   basic      => 'my ($match) = $str =~ /<\@([^|>]{9})[|>]/',
);

$_ = 'use strict; use warnings; for (1..1000) { our $str; ' . $_ . ' }'
   for values %tests;

local our $str = ('x' x 100) . '<@U03AEKYL4>' . ('x' x 100);
cmpthese(-3, \%tests);
```

Comment: @ikegami i agree..but this is cleaner code..... whereas that would require additional step of grabbing the group 1.

Comment: I don't know to what extra step you are referring.

Comment: @ikegami coming from python background ,.dont know much in perl.but hats off dude :) ...detailed analysis :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my $re = qr/<\@(\w{9})>/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say /$re/ ? "OK : $_"  : "KO : $_";
}

__DATA__
<@U03AEKYL4>
<@U03AEKWTL|agreen>
```

**Output:**

```
OK : <@U03AEKYL4>
KO : <@U03AEKWTL|agreen>
```

You may change `\w{}` in `.{9}` depending on your needs.

Comment: I think the second one is suppose to match too.